# Emmet tab stops in CodePen

Tags: emmet, codepen

When using Emmet with VS Code, there are multiple tab stops.   So the simple "a" for an anchor element allows me to tab from the href attribute to the content within the a tag.  Convenient.

That doesn't seem to work in CodePen.   Just wondering if I'm missing something ?